# Android Studio NDK project changing CMakeLists.txt path causes error (unable to find Ninja)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a native android project structure using CMake in Android Studio. I want to change the path of my CMakeLists.txt file in build.gradle which is by default `src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt` to `D:/Projects/AndroidNative/CMakeLists.txt`

After doing this change my build.gradle looks like this:
(Relevant part in "externalNativeBuild" scope)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.andndk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15',
                        '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'D:/Projects/AndroidNative/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
}
```

So when I sync my gradle project I have this error:

```
  The detected version of Ninja () is less than the version of Ninja required
```

I do have a Ninja installed and up to date, obviously because I did not have this error before changing CMakeLists path. So I don't understand why it can no longer find Ninja ?

Here is the CMake command generated:

```
Error while executing process
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe
with arguments {-HD:\Projects\AndroidNative
-BC:\Users\xxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\andndk\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\xxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\andndk\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static}
```

Comment: One possible caveat could be that the user name contains some special character, for example - space. One little space in path may drive the toolchain nuts.

Comment: I just figured out that my issue had nothing to do with changing the path but it was about the content of the new CMakeLists.txt . It is divided to 2 parts by conditional expression: if(TARGET_ANDROID) ... endif() if(TARGET_WINDOWS) ... endif() , so that I could compile from visual studio (with TARGET_WINDOWS) and android studio (with TARGET_ANDROID), for some reason in the last case it didn't work (the ninja error) even though the same CMakeLists was compiling fine with VS. It didn't come to  my mind that it would be the CMakeLists that caused the error because it was working with VS ...

Comment: Here is the CMakeLists.txt that caused the error: https://pastebin.com/JagM2MZH , If I remove "project(andndk)"  line 73 it compiles without error.

Comment: Also, Visual Studio I used CMake 3.10 to compile, AS uses CMake 3.6.4. So it may well be that it's a CMake bug that has been fixed.. idk. Anyway my question is quiet irrelevant now.